# SharePoint Site Collection - subsite error accessing site permissions page

Tags: sharepoint-online

Here's an interesting one, I'm reviewing an issue where the site owners (of a sub-site) cannot access the 'site permissions' page (/_layouts/15/user.aspx). When they try they get a access denied message.

I'm unsure of the history of the site and how this occurred. I have noticed that the groups visible in this sub-site might have been created manually (after he site was provisioned).

In the top level, where it says 'users with limited access', it displays a list of groups of other subsites. There is no group listed for the site with the issue. How can this be rectified?
As the sub-site has an owner group, associated with lists/libaries, I did not want to create a new group and re-associate with these lists/libaries :)

Thanks

Comment: Are Site collection administrators able to access site permissions?

Comment: Site collection admins, can access site permissions page and edit groups. We cannot grant Owners SCA though, hence a fix is needed for the owners to once again be able to edit groups

Answer (score 0):

**Please perform the following troubleshooting**

1. Sign in the subsite "Site Permission" page (/_layouts/15/user.aspx) of as **top-level site admin**, and check subsite owner permissions
2. Sign in the subsite "Site Permission" page (/_layouts/15/user.aspx) of as top-level site admin. Delete subsite owner's permissions, and then re-grant **Full Control** permission to subsite owner.

Comment: Is No.1 correct ? Do you mean 'Sign in the "top-level site..., and not subsite?
Also, when you say 'as top-level site admin' - can this be site collection admin?

Comment: Also, I don't believe the sub-site level group exists in the top-level, as could not find it.

Comment: Hi, OrangeJuiceJones. Thanks for your reply. I mean, as site collection administrator to access subsite "site permissions" page.

Comment: After deleting owners permissions, the owner group was removed from user.aspx page. Then I re added the group with full control. The same problem that the users within the group cannot access this page.

Comment: I have resolved by creating a new group in top-level (with no permissions), and adding that same group to sub-site with full control.

Comment: Hi, OrangeJuiceJones. I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by creating a new group in top-level (with no permissions), and adding that same group to sub-site with full control